# 'The association between entites has been severed' error when deleting child, with relationship defined in terms of compound key

Tags: entity-framework-core

So the preface: I have a pair of models, one that's defined as a 'parent' that has its own ID, properties, and fields for child components:

```cs
public class SearchDesign
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    // ... more properties
    
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<SearchComponent> SearchComponents { get; set; }
}
```

The components themselves are children to the `SearchDesign`, and are set up to also be representable as a tree.

```cs
public class SearchComponent
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int SearchDesignID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int Order { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    // ... more properties

    [DataMember]
    public virtual SearchDesign SearchDesign { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual SearchComponent ParentComponent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<SearchComponent> ChildComponents { get; set; }
}
```

These particular parts of the model are set up in a DBContext like so...

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SearchComponent>()
    .HasKey(sc => new { sc.Id, sc.SearchDesignID });

modelBuilder.Entity<SearchComponent>()
    .HasMany(parent => parent.ChildComponents)
    .WithOne(child => child.ParentComponent)
    .HasForeignKey(parent => new { parent.ParentID, parent.SearchDesignID })
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<SearchComponent>()
    .HasOne(sc => sc.SearchDesign)
    .WithMany(sd => sd.SearchComponents)
    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.SearchDesignID)
    .IsRequired(false);
```

So there is a point where I attempt to perform an Update function through an API, which calls a function that will overwrite traits on the existing entity on our DB. In the process of doing this we 'remove' the dependent components from the design, to then later re-add them in the state that's reflected in the input that comes from the request:

```cs
//Update case.
design = design.Clone(); //function that un-links the entity from EF core by using Newtonsoft to de-serialize and then re-serialize it.

SearchDesign existing = LoadDesign(design.Id);
if (existing == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
else
{
    existing.Name = design.Name;
    
    ...

    //Remove and re-add.
    DBContext.SearchComponents.RemoveRange(existing.SearchComponents); //THIS throws the error.
    foreach (var component in design.SearchComponents)
    {
        component.SearchDesign = existing;
    }
    DBContext.SearchComponents.AddRange(design.SearchComponents);
}
```

Thing is, when I attempt the `RemoveRange`, which is (I reiterate) attempting to **remove dependent elements**, it throws this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The association between entities
> 'SearchDesign' and 'SearchComponent' with the key value
> '{SearchDesignID: 7}' has been severed but the relationship is either
> marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key
> is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when
> a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use
> cascade deletes.

My instincts lead me to believe this might be something to do with the parent/child loop on the `SearchComponent` structure, but the error seems to indicate it's an issue pertaining to the design/component link? If that's really the case then this error makes no sense because I'm attempting to remove the dependent/child entity, not the parent, and I can't exactly make the `SearchDesignID` get set to null, because that's part of the element's key.

Any advice from EF Core experts would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Here's the problem: "is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable". `SearchDesignID` must be nullable for the relationship to be optional.

Comment: Right, but the `SearchDesignID` on the `SearchComponent` (the dependent entity) isn't meant to be nullable by nature. If there isn't a design it's attached to, it shouldn't exist. It's also used as the element's compound key with its own ID, and I'm not sure if the key of an element in a SQL table (or something making up that key) can be null?

Answer (score -1):

> My instincts lead me to believe this might be something to do with the parent/child loop on the SearchComponent structure

This was correct it turned out. The main issue was this part of the RootDBContext definition:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SearchComponent>()
    .HasMany(parent => parent.ChildComponents)
    .WithOne(child => child.ParentComponent)
    .HasForeignKey(parent => new { parent.ParentID, parent.SearchDesignID })
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

The Restrict Delete Behavior was what caused the error to generate. Changing it to be `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` caused the issue to stop occurring... in *unit tests* that is.

This created another issue in which the migration created due to the change couldn't be applied to my local environment database, since the migration script would provide an error about delete cascade loops. Thing is, other online sources I researched about implementing a self-referencing tree structure in EF Core used the `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` setting, and this was why.

So then the real solution was to just do the work manually - because `DbSet.RemoveRange` is usually made to delete non-recursive relationships between distinct entities, it likely was generating the error because it couldn't recognize which ones of my `SearchComponent` entities were children, and which ones were parents. Using a pretty basic depth-first tree-traversal seemed to bypass the dependency issue:

```
private void DeleteTheTree(ICollection<SearchComponent> componentsToDelete)
{
    foreach (SearchComponent component in componentsToDelete)
    {
        if (component.ChildComponents != null)
        {
            DeleteTheTree(component.ChildComponents);
        }
        DBContext.SearchComponents.Remove(component);
    }
}
```